# How to generate a weighted random list from a list of elements in Python such that all elements are picked

Tags: python

Say I have some probabilities that happen to add up to 1

```
prob=[.80,.10,.05,.02,.02,.01]
```

that correspond to the elements

```
elements=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
```

And I want to randomise the list so that each element has their probability of being picked and put into the firstmost available slot, but once picked is not picked again.

I searched StackOverflow but I could only find either selecting elements totally at random or only selecting a single item with a weighted random.

Comment: Using `numpy`: `np.random.choice(elements,len(elements),replace=False,p=prob)`

Comment: the numpy one works as random.sample() with propability due to `replace=False`  ? - nevermind it does - its even in the dupes answers